# Allow only number inputs for an asp.net form

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I am new at asp and vb languages and I was hoping for a little help on restricting input into a form. I want to restrict the inputs to only numeric entries. Currently the form functions but if any letters or symbols are entered, I get a "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' "

The form is set up with 2 inputs and a calculate button:

```
<%
Dim nInput1, nInput2, nCOLInitial, _
nYourSavings, _
nCOLSavings, _ 
sSavingsText  

nInput1 = Int(request.QueryString("nInput1"))
nInput2 = Int(request.QueryString("nInput2"))
nCOLInitial = 40

nYourSavings = ((nInput2 - nCOLInitial) * 3973) * nInput1

if  nInput2 & nInput1 = 0 Then
nCOLSavings = 0
sSavingsText = ("Default Text")
ElseIf nInput2 <= 40 Then 
nCOLSavings = 0
sSavingsText = ("No Savings") 
Else
nCOLSavings = nYourSavings * 0.3123
sSavingsText = ("Savings") 
End If
%>

<form name="form1" action="page.asp" target="_self" method="get" runat="server">
<input type="number" name="nInput1" size="15" value=<% = nInput1 %>>
<input type="number" name="nInput2" size="15" value=<% = nInput2 %>>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="B1">
</form>

<% = formatcurrency(nCOLSavings, 0) %>
<% = (sSavingsText) %>
```

I have attempted to use the following script, but it only seems to work in Chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".numeric").numeric();
$(".integer").numeric(false, function() { alert("Integers only"); this.value = ""; this.focus(); });
$(".positive").numeric({ negative: false }, function() { alert("No negative values"); this.value = ""; this.focus(); });
$(".positive-integer").numeric({ decimal: false, negative: false }, function() { alert("Positive integers only"); this.value = ""; this.focus(); });
$("#remove").click(
    function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".numeric,.integer,.positive").removeNumeric();
    }
);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to attach some validation logic to a page event, such as Page_Load() that checks if the input field is numeric, prior to using the value entered in the field. If this doesn't make sense, you will need to learn more about the ASP.NET page life cycle.

Comment: Are you using ASP or ASP.NET? These are totally different.

Comment: @DavidR I am using ASP. I have done some research into the validation logic, but it is a bit over my head. I decided the easiest thing for me to do was onkeyup="integersOnly(this)" within the input textbox and some javascript: <script type="text/javascript">
    function integersOnly(obj) {
        obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    }

Comment: I provided an answer that addresses the underlying runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged VB.Net .If the input is by a textbox.

```
If Not IsNumeric(Text1.Text) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter numbers only.", vbInformation    
 'you may also consider erasing it       
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use something like a regular expressions to limit the input:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                ControlToValidate="txtName"     
                                ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" />
</form>
```

Here is some more documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is you are attempting to CAST a non-numeric value to an Integer data type which causes the "type mismatch error" (Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d') you are seeing. The Request.QueryString collection is an array of String only, so all values are returned as String every time you access this collection.

This demonstration code will cause a runtime error, because the String "abc" cannot be converted to an Integer:

```
REM Runtime error!~
nInput1 = Int("abc")
```

To resolve this, you must first check that the inputs are numeric, using the IsNumeric() Operator. Once you have confirmed these are numeric, it is safe to perform operations on them as if they are integers.

```
<%
    Dim nInput1, nInput2, nCOLInitial, _
    nYourSavings, _
    nCOLSavings, _ 
    sSavingsText  

    REM you must check that the input fields are both numeric before CASTing to Integer using Int()
    REM If you cast a string to an integer and it fails, you will see the runtime error you experienced
    If IsNumeric(request.QueryString("nInput1")) And IsNumeric(request.QueryString("nInput2")) Then

        nInput1 = Int(request.QueryString("nInput1"))
        nInput2 = Int(request.QueryString("nInput2"))
        nCOLInitial = 40

        nYourSavings = ((nInput2 - nCOLInitial) * 3973) * nInput1

        If nInput2 & nInput1 = 0 Then
            nCOLSavings = 0
            sSavingsText = ("Default Text")
        ElseIf nInput2 <= 40 Then 
            nCOLSavings = 0
            sSavingsText = ("No Savings") 
        Else
            nCOLSavings = nYourSavings * 0.3123
            sSavingsText = ("Savings") 
        End If

    Else

        REM Add warning!
        Response.Write("Input fields must be a number!")

    End If

%>

<form name="form1" action="so20477564.asp" target="_self" method="get" runat="server">
    <input type="number" name="nInput1" size="15" value="<% = nInput1 %>">
    <input type="number" name="nInput2" size="15" value="<% = nInput2 %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="B1">
</form>
```